# simplify if .. else in javascript

Tags: javascript

my mind is blank and I can't think of the solution...

I have the following code:

```
if (onlySelected === true) {
    if (r.selected == true) {
        result.push(pushValue);
    }
}
else {
    result.push(pushValue);
}
```

how can I simplify this code into this:

```
if (condition) { result.push(pushValue) }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (!onlySelected || r.selected){
    result.push(pushValue);
}
```

or this if you absolutely need the type equality and not just truthiness:

```
if (onlySelected !== true || r.selected){
    result.push(pushValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(onlySelected === false || r.selected == true) {
    result.push(pushValue);
}
```

Comment: !== true is not equal to === false

Comment: @Bergi That makes absolutely no sense to me, so would you mind explaining why?

Comment: For example `5 !== true`, but `5` is not `=== false`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(!onlySelected || r.selected) && result.push(pushValue);
```

Comment: Using `!onlySelected` is going to result in type conversion where necessary. Judging from the fact they used the `===` comparator, rather than simply `==`, this seems incorrect.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist That's true, I was supposing that `onlySelected` was intended as a boolean value. Same for `r.selected`.

Comment: onlySelected and r.selected are indeed both boolean.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( (onlySelected === true && r.selected === true) || 1) {
    result.push(value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work:

```
if(!onlySelected || (onlySelected && r.selected))
    result.push(pushValue);
```

Comment: If `!onlySelected` is false, `onlySelected` is true so you can eliminate that one.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, this is what I made it to.

```
onlySelected === !0 ? r.selected == 1 && result.push(pushValue) : result.push(pushValue)
```